# How to access data returned from props

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I new to nextjs and react. I am using the nextjs to fetch data from api and display it in view. this is my code.

```
const Index = props => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Events</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.eventList.map(({ venue }) => (
        <li key={venue.name}>
          <a>{venue.name}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
);

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch("api link here");
  let data = await res.json();
  console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.events.length}`);
  return {
    eventList: data.events
  };
};
```

Now my api return data like this

```
[
    {
      "id": 4303920,
      "name": "Test Event",
      "venue": {
        "id": 1610,
        "name": "Eiffel Tower Viewing Deck at Paris Las Vegas",
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 4323,
      "name": "Test Event 2",
      "venue": {
        "id": 1610,
        "name": "Eiffel Tower Viewing Deck at Paris Las Vegas",
      }
    }
]
```

I am able to access the venue details by props.eventList.map function but i am not able to access the id and name.

Comment: What happens when you try your code? Is there an error? In the map if you console log “venue” what is in it?

Comment: i can access the venue fine. but when i am not able to access the name ( Test Event ). it says name is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your map instead of ({venue}) => just do (item) => your issue is you are getting each element and only extracting venue from it instead of the entire element. Once you have item you can say item.id, item.venue etc.

Comment: thanks for your help. it worked. it was so simple and i spend an hour on this.

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem, you should upvote it or mark it as solved in order to really thank the person who helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put {venue} inside your map function but pass the event like this (event) then you will have even.name and event.is and you will have event.venue.id and event.venue.name